# Оформление select

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как можно сделать свое офрмление тега селект такого вида
 [image] ?

как я понимаю, этого нельзя добиться средствами только css, и нужно использовать доп.плагины?

Answer (score 3):

Труъ-кодер всегда заменяет селект на элемент, на который вешается обработчик. Кликая по элементу, вызывается функция, которая "показывает" другой элемент, который содержит в себе данные списка.

Ну так, в теории. На практике чуть сложнее. Если нужны примерчики, могём и примерчики запилить.

Comment: покажите примерчики, пожалуйста)

Comment: @Heidel,  [Свой select html javascript css](http://lampacore.ru/2012/11/23/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-select-html-javascript-css/).

Comment: блин, мне это еще пока слишком сложно))) мне бы пока просто с оформлением разобраться))) но всё равно спасибо)))

Answer (score 2):

Вот  [пример,](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/)
а дальше уже на что фантазии хватит.

Answer (score 2):

Да, к сожалению CSS не достаточно для стилизования `<select>`, `<input type="radio">` и `<input type="checkbox">`, для этого требуются дополнения.
Могу только посоветовать подборку [jQuery плагинов](http://habrahabr.ru/company/aiken/blog/114927/)